# Sort a subset of columns for rows matching condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rows

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
     a b  c d e f g
   0 x y  1 3 4 5 6
   1 x y -1 7 8 5 6
   2 x y -1 7 8 3 4
```

For rows where `df.c == -1`   I would like to sort all the columns between `df.d` and `df.g` in ascending order.

The result would be:

```
     a b  c d e f g
   0 x y  1 3 4 5 6
   1 x y -1 5 6 7 8
   2 x y -1 3 4 7 8
```

I tried several things but none seemed to work:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
if row.c == -1:
    subset = row[4:]
    sorted = sorted(subset)
    df.replace(to_replace=subset, value= sorted)
```

and also

```
df.loc[df.c == -1, df[4:]] = sorted(df[4:])
```

Comment: I don't want to "move" the column label while sorting. I need them to stay the way they are but the values have to be sorted. I'm not sure I'm clear enough, sorry. Tell me if you need more infos !

edit: Where c!=-1 i need the row to stay unchanged, possibly to stay at the place they are but if they are moved to top or bottom it doesn't matter much, I can still sort based on df.a afterward.

Comment: No it makes sense. I thought you wanted to sort the rows, but realized you need to sort the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) on the region of interest.

```
mask = df.c.eq(-1), slice('d', 'g')

df.loc[mask] = np.sort(df.loc[mask].values)

df
#    a  b  c  d  e  f  g
# 0  x  y  1  3  4  5  6
# 1  x  y -1  5  6  7  8
# 2  x  y -1  3  4  7  8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked very well and very efficiently !

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the fastest, but this works:

```
rmask = df.c == -1
cmask = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
df.loc[rmask, cmask] = df.loc[rmask, cmask].apply(lambda row: sorted(row), axis=1)
df
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
0  x  y  1  3  4  5  6
1  x  y -1  5  6  7  8
2  x  y -1  3  4  7  8
```